# Reshape long to wide efficiently with amount variable and several ID variables

Tags: r, reshape2

I have data resembling a much, much larger version of the first chart below. I would like to "unmelt" it into the second chart, but I cannot do it efficiently. At the bottom, I have my most recent attempt where IDVars is the first three columns below, essentially. It ran for 15 minutes before I needed to kill it.

| Name | ID | Trial | Variable | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Name 1 | 1 | 1 | FinalSalary | 300.00 |
| Name 1 | 1 | 1 | FinalDCBalance | 400.00 |
| Name 1 | 1 | 2 | FinalSalary | 300.00 |
| Name 1 | 1 | 2 | FinalDCBalance | 300.00 |
| Name 2 | 2 | 1 | FinalSalary | 400.00 |
| Name 2 | 2 | 1 | FinalDCBalance | 400.00 |
| Name 2 | 2 | 2 | FinalSalary | 200.00 |
| Name 2 | 2 | 2 | FinalDCBalance | 300.00 |
| Name 3 | 3 | 1 | FinalSalary | 100.00 |
| Name 3 | 3 | 2 | FinalDCBalance | 400.00 |

| Name | ID | Trial | FinalSalary | FinalDCBalance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Name 1 | 1 | 1 | 300 | 400 |
| Name 1 | 1 | 2 | 300 | 300 |
| Name 2 | 2 | 1 | 400 | 400 |
| Name 2 | 2 | 2 | 200 | 300 |
| Name 3 | 3 | 1 | 100 | 400 |
| Name 3 | 3 | 2 | 300 | 100 |

```
unmelt <- reshape(dataframe, idvar = IDVars, v.names = 'variable', direction = 'wide', timevar = 'Amount')
```

Comment: maybe try `data.table::dcast`

Comment: @Connor What is `IDVars` ? Also, there is no row in your example data with `Name 3` and `Trial == 2`. Can you clarify? Please share `dput(head(your_data, 15))`.

Comment: @Markus IDVars is essentially c('Name','ID','Trial'), using the above as an example. There are more matching IDs in the actual data. What you saw was a typo and I corrected it in the chart above.

Comment: @ConnorJoseph Can you try `reshape(df1, idvar = c("Name", "ID", "Trial"), timevar = "Variable", direction = "wide")` There should be 2 `NA`s given your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `pivot_wider`

```
library(tidyr)
pivot_wider(df1, names_from = 'Variable', values_from = 'Amount')
```

Answer (score 1):

The `timevar=` should be `"Variable"`, not `"Amount"`.  The idvar columns go along the side, the timevar column goes along the top and everything else (Amount) goes in the body of the output as the values.  `v.names = "Amount"` could be specified but it will figure it out because that is the only column left so we omitted it.

```
r <- reshape(dd, dir = "wide", idvar = c("Name", "ID", "Trial"), timevar = "Variable")
names(r) <- sub("Amount.", "", names(r)) # optional
```

giving:

```
> r
     Name ID Trial FinalSalary FinalDCBalance
1  Name 1  1     1         300            400
3  Name 1  1     2         300            300
5  Name 2  2     1         400            400
7  Name 2  2     2         200            300
9  Name 3  3     1         100             NA
10 Name 3  3     2          NA            400
```

### Note

The input in reproducible form:

```
dd <- structure(list(Name = c("Name 1", "Name 1", "Name 1", "Name 1", 
"Name 2", "Name 2", "Name 2", "Name 2", "Name 3", "Name 3"), 
    ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), Trial = c(1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L), Variable = c("FinalSalary", 
    "FinalDCBalance", "FinalSalary", "FinalDCBalance", "FinalSalary", 
    "FinalDCBalance", "FinalSalary", "FinalDCBalance", "FinalSalary", 
    "FinalDCBalance"), Amount = c(300, 400, 300, 300, 400, 400, 
    200, 300, 100, 400)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```